Terraform: Error refreshing state: unsupported checkable object kind "var"
When performing a Terraform run using GitHub actions, I encountered the error below:
Terraform Init    

Run terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
Error refreshing state: unsupported checkable object kind "var"
Error: Terraform exited with code 1.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I checked to see if there was some variable that does not have an assigned value, and I found none.
This is my current github-actions.yml file:
on:
  push:
    branches: [develop]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, develop]

env:
  AWS_REGION: us-west-2
  TF_VERSION: 1.5.0


Here's how I fixed the issue
The issue is due to version mismatch between my local Terraform (v1.9.6) and GitHub Actions (v1.5.0). I had to update the GitHub Actions workflow to use a compatible version:
on:
  push:
    branches: [develop]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, develop]

env:
  AWS_REGION: us-west-2
  TF_VERSION: 1.9.8  # Updated to latest version

I updated the TF_VERSION from 1.5.0 to 1.9.8 in the env variables section. This will ensure that both the local and GitHub environments are using compatible versions.
References:
Failed to load state: unsupported checkable object kind var
